# How to discretize large dataframe by columns with variable bins in Pandas/Dask

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parallel-processing, dask

I am able to discretize a Pandas dataframe by columns with this code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def discretize(X, n_scale=1):

    for c in X.columns:
        loc = X[c].median()

        # median absolute deviation of the column
        scale = mad(X[c])

        bins = [-np.inf, loc - (scale * n_scale),
                loc + (scale * n_scale), np.inf]
        X[c] = pd.cut(X[c], bins, labels=[-1, 0, 1])

    return X
```

I want to discretize each column using as parameters: loc (the median of the column) and scale (the [median absolute deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation) of the column).

With small dataframes the time required is acceptable (since it is a single thread solution).

However, with larger dataframes I want to exploit more threads (or processes) to speed up the computation.

I am no expert of [Dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/index.html), which should provide the solution for this problem.

However, in my case the discretization should be feasible with the code:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def discretize(X, n_scale=1):

    # I'm using only 2 partitions for this example
    X_dask = dd.from_pandas(X, npartitions=2)

    # FIXME: 
    # how can I define bins to compute loc and scale
    # for each column?
    bins = [-np.inf, loc - (scale * n_scale),
            loc + (scale * n_scale), np.inf]

    X = X_dask.apply(pd.cut, axis=1, args=(bins,), labels=[-1, 0, 1]).compute()

    return X
```

but the problem here is that `loc` and `scale` are dependent on column values, so they should be computed for each column, either before or during the apply.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used `dask`, but I guess you can define a new function to be used in `apply`.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def discretize(X, n_scale=1):

    X_dask = dd.from_pandas(X.T, npartitions=mp.cpu_count()+1)
    X = X_dask.apply(_discretize_series,
                     axis=1, args=(n_scale,),
                     columns=X.columns).compute().T

    return X

def _discretize_series(x, n_scale=1):

    loc = x.median()
    scale = mad(x)
    bins = [-np.inf, loc - (scale * n_scale),
            loc + (scale * n_scale), np.inf]
    x = pd.cut(x, bins, labels=[-1, 0, 1])

    return x
```

Comment: Thanks. I edited your question with the working solution. Please accept it if you think it suffices.